# Permalink with duplicate titles

Tags: php, wordpress

is it possible to use same post titles for different categories with pretty permalink?

I want to have /%category%/%postname%.html permalinks and two posts with the same title "Post title" in different categories "Category 1" and "Category 2"
So I want following links:

```
> http://www.example.com/category-1/post-title.html
> http://www.example.com/category-2/post-title.html
```

But when I publish the second post, then its URL is changed to post-title-2, so URL is `http://www.example.com/category-2/post-title-2.html`

So, I want duplicities in post titles, but not in the whole URL, because of other category. Is there an any way to achieve this?

Comment: post-title-2.html This is your slug of the post, not a title. in WordPress, if you create posts with the same name it will change slug but title remains same

Comment: yes, I want the same slug of the post but different categories, how does it fix?

Comment: Category and Post name generate don't have dependent. What's do you want with this link?

Comment: Hello Quỳnh Nguyễn, i want to same slug-title (ex: "post-title") but different categories.

Comment: Post name slug generate from WP Permalink not dependent on Category. So I think this is impossible. Tell me what you will do next with this link. Why must have same slug?

Comment: Because: 
hospital-com/room-a/nguyen-van-a.html
hospital-com/room-b/nguyen-van-a.html => hospital-com/room-b/nguyen-van-a-2.html
but not working with wordpress.

Comment: It's worked with me: /uncategorized/hello-world.html and test/hello-world-2.html Hello word are 2 posts.

Comment: If is one post we have: test/hello-world.html and uncategorized/hello-world.html -- Working too.

Comment: thank Quỳnh Nguyễn, but i think that impossible for my problem. Where are you ? i'm living in Vietnamese.

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong you need to create new rewrite rules something like this

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'post_name_rewrite_rule');
function post_name_rewrite_rule($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();
    $post = get_post();
    foreach ($post as $post) {
        $post_name = preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', $post->name);
        $new_rules['/'.$post->slug}.'/'] = '/'.url_encode($post_name).'/';
    }
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```

Comment: sorry, it don't work. you wrong: $new_rules['/'.$post->slug}.'/']. but when i fix and use still not work.

Comment: this here i find an answer and i disappoint
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95758/allow-duplicate-permalink-slugs-for-posts-in-different-categories

Comment: @NguyễnVinh       Even if his answer didn't not help you; you should not be rude because he spent his time & energy trying to help. And, there is no guarantee he'd be 100% right. Being Polite is just only about Manners.

Comment: thank you Raj Kumar Bhardwaj for help me. thank Poiz